# Display Reward Points on Product Page in Magento 2 EE

Tags: magento2, magento2-enterprise, reward-points, magento-reward

I have setup a custom module to display some information underneath the 'Add to Cart' button on product pages. The information that I would like to display is the amount of reward points that a customer can obtain by purchasing the product.

The reward points are taken care of by the default Magento 2 EE rewards module (magento/module-reward).

Is there a way to programmatically get the reward points for each product?

Cheers,
Max